# AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'input' when trying to use 'Model'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am getting this error when using that 'Model' model in Keras. Here is my code:

```
embedding_units = 300

model = Sequential([
Dense(embedding_units, input_shape=(2048,), activation='relu'),
RepeatVector(max_length) 
])

modelb = Sequential([
Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_units, input_length=max_length),
LSTM(256, return_sequences=True),
TimeDistributed(Dense(300)),
])

merged_model = concatenate([model.output, modelb.output], axis=1)

merged_model = Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True))(merged_model)
merged_model = TimeDistributed(Dense(vocab_size))(merged_model)
final_model = Activation('softmax')(merged_model)

model = Model([model.input, modelb.input], final_model)
```

The error that I get is as follows:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-664f1b1c74f6> in <module>()
    22 final_model = Activation('softmax')(merged_model)
    23 
---> 24 model = Model([model_imgs.input, captioning_model.input], out)

AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'input'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it intentional that you override the  `model_imgs` Dense layer with a RepeatVector layer?

Right now you are overriding the Dense layer `model_imgs` with the RepeatVector layer. However you are **not** connecting this RepeatVector layer to the model at all. I suggest the following:

```
model = Input(shape=(2048,))
model_imgs = Dense(embedding_units, activation='relu')(model)
model_imgs = RepeatVector(max_length)(model_imgs) # <--- 1. initialize RepeatVector 2. call the created object => now model_imgs is connected to the whole model starting from input

captioning_model = Embedding(vocab_size, embedding_units, input_length=max_length)(model)
captioning_model = LSTM(256, return_sequences=True)(captioning_model)
captioning_model = TimeDistributed(Dense(256))(captioning_model)
                        
merged_model = concatenate([model_imgs, captioning_model], axis=1)

merged_model = Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True))(x)
merged_model = TimeDistributed(Dense(vocab_size))(merged_model)
final_model = Activation('softmax')(merged_model)
```

Comment: Sorry I used the wrong model for my problem so I changed the question. Can you help with my question?

Comment: Please post the full code. I do not know how you initialize `model_imgs` or `captioning_model`, even though that is causing the error. Also I see syntax errors in your code in the creation of `model`: you are not closing the list of layers.